# VXLAN / EVPN Types

Tags: bgp, vxlan

Looking into EVPN and the route types (type 2 and 5) is my understanding correct.
In terms of their placement into the relevant forward tables upon the device.

**EVPN Route Type 2: MAC/IP Advertisement**
Placed into the mac forwarding table.

**EVPN Route Type 5: IP Prefix Route**
Are placed into the RIB

With both route types also being placed into the VTEP tables. Is this understanding correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

You need route type 2 messages to fill your ARP tables since there's no traditional broadcast domain anymore. You can find more details on type 2 messages in [RFC7432](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7432).

Type 5 routes are used, as you assumed, to fill routing tables, as described in [draft-ietf-bess-evpn-prefix-advertisement](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-bess-evpn-prefix-advertisement), which also explains some of the use cases for this route type.

There's a [nice article on bgphelp.com](http://bgphelp.com/2017/05/22/evpn-route-types/) about all the BGP EVPN route types.

Comment: It does not contain tables. It contains IP/MAC combinations which can be used to fill forwarding tables.

Answer (score 2):

I am quoting from the book ' MPLS in the SDN Era'.

When IRB is configured in an EVPN ,  there are two EVPN Type 2 routes:

> • A good old MAC Advertisement route, which just the IRB’s MAC in the
>   NLRI.
>   • A juicier MAC/IP Advertisement route (also Type 2), which
>   contains both the IRB’s MAC and IPv4 address in the NLRI.

So from this perspective , the EVPN Type 2 routes contain IRB IPs as well IRB MAC Addresses (MAC + IP). This is in addition to simple MAC Addresses that are learned via MBGP.

In my openion , EVPN Type 5 routes are pure Layer 3 IP Addresses that are advertised just like L3VPN case.

Comment: Thanks it was more confirmation about their placements within the necessary tables...